# Cannot pull ansible docker image

Tags: ansible

```
$ docker pull ansible/ansible
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for ansible/ansible:latest not found
```

I try and get started with ansible but I get the above error message trying to pull the Docker image. Is it broken or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If run you `docker pull <image>`, you are implicitly asking for a tag named `latest`.  There is no such tag available from the Ansible repository.  You can see a list of available tags at https://hub.docker.com/r/ansible/ansible/tags/.

For example, if you wanted the `fedora27py3` version of the image, you would run:

```
docker pull ansible/ansible:fedora27py3
```

I note that the most recent of thoses images is 7 months old. If you're experimenting iwth Ansible you might want to just install it into a Python virtual environment.